Is there a solution to push project folder to GitHub
Everytime I try to add the project folder, it gives an error of Failed to add files due to "caches/transforms" these new folders that came with the new version. I get annoyed but this error whenever i try to push the projecet as well and it fails to push because the "caches/transforms" its been days now
I deleted the Android Studio and installed it and started a new project but still, there`s no changes. The error still occurs.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I hope this helps you:

then click on share
Note make sure you have logged in to your GitHub or Gitlab account in Android Studio
After sharing project you can easily commit and push your changes.
